# Deleting every second char in double linked list

Tags: python, dll

This is my main function and I cannot change it:

```
L = Lista(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']) 

ispis(izdvoji(L)) 
ispis(L)
```

In this piece of code I have to make new double linked list and put every second char into it and then remove it from original double linked list:

```
def izdvoji(self):
    doubleLinked = DoublyLinkedList()
    temp = self.head
    i=0
    while (temp != None):
        if isinstance(temp.data, str) and (i%2)==0:
            i = i+1
            doubleLinked.append(temp.data)
            
            self.delete(temp.data)
        temp = temp.next
    return doubleLinked
```

This is my delete function:

```
def delete(self, key):
        cur = self.head
        while cur:
            if cur.data == key and cur  == self.head:
                if not cur.next:
                    cur = None
                    self.head = None
                    return

                else:
                    nxt = cur.next
                    cur.next = None
                    nxt.prev = None
                    cur = None
                    self.head = nxt
                    return

            elif cur.data == key:
                if cur.next:
                    nxt = cur.next
                    prev = cur.prev
                    prev.next = nxt
                    nxt.prev = prev
                    cur.next = None
                    cur.prev = None
                    cur = None
                    return
            
                else:
                    prev = cur.prev
                    prev.next = None
                    cur.prev = None
                    cur = None
                    return
            cur = cur.next
```

When I print it I only got:

a

but I need a c e g

b, c, d, e, f, g, h

Comment: Anyone else, I think my mistake is I delete node and in node is only 'a'?

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of a python sequence slice.

Python sequence slice addresses can be written as `a[start:end:step]` and any of start, stop or end can be dropped. `a[::3]` is every third element of the sequence.

An example of what you may need:

```
L = (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])

print(L[::2])
```

From here, you may add or delete what you need to.

Comment: But I cannot change main part. I'm trying to do it in function izdvoji.